# Some properties of elements in an array throw ‘not assignable to DetailedHTMLProps’ error

Tags: css, arrays, reactjs, typescript, properties

Working with TypeScript and React, I’m trying to place image elements who each have unique inline positioning. I’ve created an array of the elements - the ubiquitous color blobs folks are using these days - each with their own specific CSS inline properties, which are then passed to the `return()` function to render out.

The problem is that some properties will compile and render just fine, but others will throw errors like:

```
Type '{ alt: string; left: number; src: string; "z-index": number; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>'.
  Property 'left' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>'.ts(2322)
```

The code I have is:

```js
import stuff from ‘stuff’;
…

const Home = () => {
    const blobs = [
    {
      id: 1,
      blob: yellowBlob1,
      zIndex: -1,
      position: 'absolute',
      left: -7.97,
      top: -5.25,
      transform: 0,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
    …
    ]

    return(
        <>
            <BlobRow>
                {blobs.map((blobs) => (
                    <Col key={blobs.id}>
                        <img
                            alt=''
                            //left={blobs.left}
                            //position='absolute'
                            src={blobs.blob}
                            //top={blobs.top}'rem'
                            //transform={blobs.transform}
                            z-index={blobs.zIndex}
                        />
                    </Col>
                ))}
            </BlobRow>
        …
        </>
    );
};
```

Now, as-is, this code will render out four colored blobs in a row, each as its own column and behind the foreground text and buttons. Perfect.
BUT…
As soon as I uncomment any of the commented-out properties, I get errors like the one above. The `blobs` array already has the type `any`; types `string` and `number` are present both in properties that compile and ones that don’t; and trying to place any kind of unit declaration - %, px, rem - will throw their own fun errors.

I can’t see what the common threads are between the properties that will compile and the ones that won’t and thus how to fix them. What is it that I’m overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out that the core problem was I was effectively applying invalid inline styles to an object that couldn't take them: specifically, transform styles to an object that was in a default static position. Basically, I was working with the right ideas but wrong syntax and placement. This was the code that got around the errors, rendered a page, and cleared the way for me to end this fight with JSX and just fight with CSS:

```js
const Home = () => {
  const blobs = [
    {
      id: 1,
      blob: yellowBlob1,
      zIndex: -1,
      left: '-8%',
      top: '-84px',
      transform: 'height(41.5em) rotate(0deg) width(45em)',
      opacity: 0.85,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
    ...
    }

    <BlobRow>
        {blobs.map((blobs) => (
            <img
                alt=''
                key={blobs.id}
                src={blobs.blob}
                style={{
                  left: blobs.left,
                  opacity: blobs.opacity,
                  transform: blobs.transform,
                }}
                z-index={blobs.zIndex}
                    />
</BlobRow>

const BlobRow = styled(Row)`
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0.6;
  display: flex;

  img {
    position: absolute;
  }
`;
```

Hopefully this will help someone else in the future with JSX/CSS issues and trying to make flexible components.